# Laravel 5 and Github Integration

Tags: git, laravel-5, github-api

I've found an interesting package for Laravel 5 at https://github.com/GrahamCampbell/Laravel-GitHub an thought of giving it a try. The only problem is the lack of documentation. I was just wondering if anyone knows or could point point me the way how I can go about using the package.

I'm particularly keen on the concept of getting the latest commits done on particular repository rather than oAuth client or such.

Anybody here got an idea?

Comment: https://packagist.org/packages/graham-campbell/github  .. With Real Example ..

Comment: That is just the exact copy of the link I just mentioned.

Comment: @JhourladEstrella Have you figured it out? I need some help with this and documentation isn't really helping me.